# How do you call a methode/function from razorcomponent-part (Maui / Blazor)?

Tags: blazor, maui, function-call

I have a MauiBlazor app and want to navigate back to the indexpage if true:

```cs
    @page "/start"
    @inject NavigationManager NavMan

    @if (true)
    {
        @(() => NavMan.NavigateTo("/"))
    }
```

Output on screen is a text:"System.Action"
I did expect it to navigate back to index-page!

Why and how do I do this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your writing Razor markup not C# code.

The Razor compiler evaluates:

```cs
() => NavMan.NavigateTo("/")
```

literally as a `System.Action`.

To execute code you can define a RenderFragment.  At which point you can roll in your conditional code as well.

```cs
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

@(this.CheckIfWeNeedToGoToHome)

@code {
    private RenderFragment CheckIfWeNeedToGoToHome => (builder) =>
    {
        if (true)
            NavMan.NavigateTo("/");
    };
}
```

Comment: What is ... => (builder) => ... ?

Comment: A RenderFragment is a delegate with the following pattern 
`void RenderFragment(RenderTreeBuilder builder)`.  In the code above we're creating an anonymous method based on the pattern and assigning it to a variable of type `RenderFragment`.  `Builder` is a `RenderTreeBuilder` instance passed into the method by the Renderer when it executes the render fragment to build.